# bootstrap-sass display error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to use bootstrap-sass

It seems as if it is not compiling correctly of sorts

calling bootstrap in custom.css.scss
@import "bootstrap";

including the gem
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 2.1.1.0"

You can see the issue here, the nav is coming out white with the links off color as well.

http://learingisfun.herokuapp.com/pages/home

The repo for this as well is https://github.com/thebusiness11/appsample

Comment: Correct, I edited and corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootstrap navigation/navbar is white by default (since 2.1.0), you need to add the class `navbar-inverse` to the navigation element if you want it to be black/inversed.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

```
class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse"
```

Comment: Got it thanks, the sources I am using to learn just haven't updated with that info yet, I thought something further was broken.

Also its "inverse" not "inversed"

<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">